# Automatically select GCE instance zone in Cloud Dataflow?

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow

Is there a way to have the Dataflow service automatically select a GCE zone for a Dataflow job?

Our use case for Dataflow involves running many jobs concurrently. We have a quota of GCE instances in each of the 6 GCP zones and would like to fully utilize those quotas by distributing our jobs amongst them. This load balancing could be performed on our end, but the Dataflow service is in a better position to select a zone given that they have access to information on the entire state of the cloud center in the zone.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not currently possible in Dataflow, though it is something that the team would like to pursue in the future.